# Implementing correct JDBC connection pooling

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have multiple classes for creating DAO objects for my table. Each of them has its own connection object and I'm a little bit confused if I implemented connection pooling correctly.

It seems like every time I create a DAO object JDBC would give me a new connection but not that connection that I closed previously. How can implement correct thread safe connection pooling?

```
public class JDBCTabletDAO implements TabletDAO {
static {
    new DOMConfigurator().doConfigure("EPAM6 Final Task\\properties\\log4j.xml", org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
}

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(JDBCTabletDAO.class));
/**
 * connection for interacting with sql
 */
private Connection connection;
/**
 * data source for specified schema
 */
private DataSource dataSource;

/**
 * gets the connection from connection pool
 * @throws NamingException
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public JDBCTabletDAO() throws NamingException, SQLException{
    Context envCtx = new InitialContext();
    dataSource = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/pharmacy");
    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
}

@Override
public void delete(int tabletId) {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try{
        if(connection.isClosed())
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM tablets WHERE idTablet=?");
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, tabletId);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        DbUtil.close(preparedStatement);
        DbUtil.close(connection);
    }
}

@Override
public void update(Tablet tablet) {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try{
        if(connection.isClosed())
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE tablets SET name=?," +
                "price=?, type_id=?, description=?, need_recipe=?, weight_of_pack=?, pills_count=? WHERE idTablet=?;");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, tablet.getName());
        preparedStatement.setDouble(2, tablet.getPrice());
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, tablet.getTypeId());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, tablet.getDescription());
        preparedStatement.setBoolean(5, tablet.isNeedRecepie());
        preparedStatement.setDouble(6, tablet.getWeight());
        preparedStatement.setInt(7, tablet.getPillsCount());
        preparedStatement.setInt(8, tablet.getTabletId());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        DbUtil.close(preparedStatement);
        DbUtil.close(connection);
    }
}
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" crossContext="true" reloadable="true" path="patient/account">
    <Resource
            name="jdbc/pharmacy"
            author="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="64"
            maxIdle="8"
            maxWait="10000"
            username="root"
            password="blablabla"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pharmacy"  />
</Context>
```

Comment: You seem to assume you always get the same connection: that is not how connection pooling works, and even if you get the same **physical** connection, that does not mean you get the same **logical** connection (wrapper).

Comment: Also, remove the connection field. Make it a **local** variable. If two threads happen to call update() concurrently, they will use the same connection. One thread will close it, the other thread will get an exception trying to use it, ACID will be lost. There is no reason to have this field. Just get a connection at the beginning of the method, store it in a local variable, and close it in a finally block.

Comment: @JBNizet i used used lock's on every operation wich affect's table info

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so then i don't quite understand the real sense of connection pooling..

Comment: Connection pooling, in short, consists in having a set of opened connections available for the application. When you need to start a new transaction, you get a connection from the pool, do your transactional work, and then commit and close the connection. Closing the connection doesn't really close the physical connection, it just gives it back to the pool. The key points is that each transaction uses its own connection, and doesn't share it with others like you're doing, and that connection must be closed properly.